Creating Named Credentials via Connect API
I'm testing creating named credentials via connect api. Is this the right way of doing it?
Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_setup_named_credential.htm?q=named%20cre


From your image it looks like you are using PUT request, which can only be used to replace records and not create.
For creating named creds, you need to fire POST request as defined here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_named_credential.htm
